# Python parse dirs, remove subdirectory tree

Tags: python, parsing, directory

I have a long list of directories, with something like this

```
C:\Users\vanstrie\Desktop\ntnu\SCHEMA\2012\07_paper\results\026\onsets
```

I want to parse through folders 001-040 (026 shown above) and remove the onsets subdirectory with all files and subfolders that are in it. I am unsure how to achieve this with python 3. If you have a solution, please advise. Many thanks in advance.

Niels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that something like this should work...

```
import glob
import os.path
import shutil
files_dirs = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\vanstrie\Desktop\ntnu\SCHEMA\2012\07_paper\results\*')
for d in files_dirs:
    head,tail = os.path.split(d)
    try:
        if (0 < int(tail) < 41) and (len(tail) == 3):  #don't want to delete `\results\3\onsets` I guess...
           print("about to delete:",d)
           shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(d,'onsets'),ignore_errors=True)
    except ValueError:  #apparently we got a non-integer.  Leave that directory.
        pass
```

As with anything when deleting files, I would definitely print the things that would be deleted on a first pass -- Just to make sure the script is actually working as expected (and to make sure you don't delete something you want to keep).

Comment: will try it out in a moment and update the result. A million thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import shutil, os.path

root_folder = "C:\\Users\\vanstrie\\Desktop\\ntnu\\SCHEMA\\2012\\07_paper\\results"
suffix = "onsets"

for i in range(1,41):
  folder = os.path.join( root_folder, "%03d" % i, suffix )
  shutil.rmtree( folder, ignore_errors=True, onerror=None )
```

Comment: This is kind of nice.  I don't use `rmtree` frequently, but I'm guessing this will pass silently if the directory doesn't exist (due to `ignore_errors = True`).  If so, that makes this a much more concise answer than mine...(+1)